How to change indent size to 4 in Nx workspace for all files including config files at root level?
I created workspace using Nx, i managed to changed indent size to 4 using generated .editorconfig file.
# Editor configuration, see http://editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
max_line_length = off
trim_trailing_whitespace = false

but config files at root level like json are still using indent size 2, which is annoying.
I am reverting changes i did and here are the original files.
.editorconfig
# Editor configuration, see http://editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
max_line_length = off
trim_trailing_whitespace = false

.prettierrc
{
  "singleQuote": true
}

.eslintrc.json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "**/*"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@nx"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts",
        "*.tsx"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@nx/typescript"
        ],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.js",
        "*.jsx"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@nx/javascript"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.spec.ts",
        "*.spec.tsx",
        "*.spec.js",
        "*.spec.jsx"
      ],
      "env": {
        "jest": true
      },
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}

I tried changing .prettierrc file with tabWidth: 4, useTabs: false and also tried modifying my .eslintrc.json
{
        "files": [
          "*.json"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "prettier/prettier": [
            "error",
            {
              "tabWidth": 4,
              "useTabs": false
            }
          ]
        }
      }

but it didn't worked, my vs-code settings are set to 4 by default but i think it got overwritten by prttier, that's why it isn't changing indent size on save.
